# Check if tag is in array (October CMS Blog)

Tags: octobercms

I'm trying to check if a specific tag is in the list, and if it is, to do something (obvi). 
I've looked online and found it was apparently possible, but I don't know the proper way to formulate that.

Here is what I have so far:

```
{% set posts = headlineNews.posts %}
{% set myVar = "My Tag" %} // Set the name I want to find

{% for post in posts %}

    {% if myVar in post.tags.name %} // Look through the list of tags and check if it's inside

        Do Something

    {% else %} // if it's not inside

        Do Something Else

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

What am I doing wrong exactly?

Answer (score 0):

> You could use `pluck` method to convert tag collection to its `name` array and search through it

```html
{% set posts = headlineNews.posts %}
{% set tagNameToCheck = "mobile" %}

{% for post in posts %}
    {% if tagNameToCheck in post.tags.pluck('name') %}
        <h1>found</h1>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

> **Answer of your question :)** : What am I doing wrong exactly? => you probably searching tag name in collection of models not in collection of `name's` array

if any doubts please comment